# I need help reversing this SQL, to get the result I'm after

Tags: sql

Retyping the question.
When a new order is placed, an ORDERS_ID is created in the table ORDERS.
The ordered products is put in the table ORDERS_PRODUCTS.
By default the field PRODUCTS_TILLVERKAD is set to nothing.
As the ordered products are being manufactured the field PRODUCTS_TILLVERKAD is increased to match the requested amount, PRODUCTS_QUANTITY. When they match the line is done.

We have a screen that shows how many orders is in the system, and how many products that is in cue to be manufactured. I want to add info about how many orders that have all its products line set as finished and are waiting to be packed/shipped.

I have come upp with this so far, but it gives me all orders have one or more of the products set as finished. I only want the counter to count the orders that have ALL of its corresponding product lines ready.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as value FROM
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM orders o LEFT JOIN orders_products op ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
    WHERE op.products_tillverkad = op.products_quantity AND o.orders_status = 1
    GROUP BY o.orders_id
) AS Q


Table: ORDERS
Fields: 
ORDERS_ID
ORDERS_STATUS (1= New order, not shipped out)

Table: ORDERS_PRODUCTS
Fileds:
ORDERS_ID
PRODUCTS_QUANTITY (Quantity requested)
PRODUCTS_TILLVERKAD (Quantity manufactured)
```

Im happy to answer any questions about this, have been trying for several days now =)

Comment: `SELECT o.orders_id, count(o.orders_id) as count
    FROM orders o LEFT JOIN orders_products op ON o.orders_id = op.orders_id
    WHERE op.products_tillverkad = op.products_quantity AND o.orders_status = 1
    GROUP BY o.orders_id`

Comment: your question is not clear please update your question adding a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Edited the question a bit..